# Bound for non-integer power of sum

Tags: inequality, binomial-theorem

Let $x > 1$, $y \in (0,1)$ and $z \in (0,1)$.
I need to bound
$$(x+y)^z - x^z \leq B_z(x)$$
where I guess something like $B_z(x) \approx x^{z-1}$.

Is there anything known on these non-integer powers of sums?

Thanks..

Comment: The biggest difference is when $y=1$.  So $B_z(x) = (x+1)^z-x^z$.

Comment: You can bound $(x+1)^z-x^z$ as follows:  Define $h(x)=x^z$.  Then $h'(x) = zx^{z-1}$ has nonincreasing derivative and $$(x+1)^z=h(x+1)=h(x) + \int_x^{x+1}h'(t)dt \leq h(x) + \int_x^{x+1}h'(x)dt = h(x) + h'(x)=x^z +zx^{z-1}$$

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Michael: That looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: @joriki , well, it did not seem like a homework problem (perhaps it was?)  Is that what you mean?  That it is not good to give full answers if it is a homework problem?

Comment: @Michael: No, quite the opposite :-) I'm not as worried about homework as many others on the site. I'm more worried about questions remaining open because people answer them in the comments and then no-one bothers to write an answer that could be marked accepted. In fact it says in the comment box (when it's empty): "Avoid answering questions in comments." :-) I sometimes write community wiki answers repeating such comments, just to allow the question to be marked answered.

Comment: I sometimes like to go back on my list of solutions to look at something again. So, I do not want my list of solutions to be too cluttered, which is why I often just give comments.  In this case it turned out my comment was an answer itself.  Anyway, I have now given it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $h(x) = x^z$.  Then: 
$$ (x+y)^z - x^z \leq (x+1)^z - x^z = h(x+1)-h(x)$$
Note that $h'(x) = zx^{z-1}$ is nonincreasing in $x$. We then have: 
\begin{align}
h(x+1) &= h(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1}h'(t)dt \\
&\leq h(x) + \int_x^{x+1}h'(x)dt \: \: \: \: \mbox{[since $h'(t)$ is nonincreasing]}\\
&= h(x) + h'(x) \\
&= h(x) + zx^{z-1}
\end{align}
Thus, we can define $B_z(x) = zx^{z-1}$.